# How to standardize properties and dynamically assign fillColor variable in leaflet

Tags: javascript, loops, leaflet, gis, polygon

**How can i define a standard scale for all different feature properties and dynamically change the variable that is used to get the value of the fill_Color property?**

My fill_color properties have very different scales i.e some are in the 10-90 example (number of years)  others 1000-9000 (cost)
How can i standardize them so that return color should be based on a standard scale rather than actual numbers in leaflet?

```
function get_Color(prop){
    return prop > 400 ? '#800026':
    prop > 200 ? '#BD0026':
    prop > 100 ? '#E31A1C':
    prop > 50  ? '#FC4E2A':
    prop > 20  ? '#FD8D3C':
    prop > 10  ? '#FED976':
              '#FFEDA0'; 
}

function set_Style(feature){
  return {
   fill_Color:get_Color(feature.properties.years) //or fill_Color:get_Color(feature.properties.price)
}
}
```

Comment: What are you look for?

Comment: @Andrew You are using ternary operators.

Answer (score 0):

Change `fill_Color` to `fillColor`:

```
function get_Color(prop){
    return prop > 400 ? '#800026':
    prop > 200 ? '#BD0026':
    prop > 100 ? '#E31A1C':
    prop > 50  ? '#FC4E2A':
    prop > 20  ? '#FD8D3C':
    prop > 10  ? '#FED976':
              '#FFEDA0'; 
}

function set_Style(feature){
  return {
   fillColor: get_Color(feature.properties.population)
  }
}
```

[Leaflet Path Styles](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.7.1.html#path-fillcolor)